# Buy premium services in web, store purchases in CloudKit, avoid pay 30%

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, cloudkit, cloudkit-web-services

If I create a CloudKit connected website, where users could buy premium services to the app, an e-purchase system would implemented and when purchase completes, I would store a Purchase `recordType` and then I would enable use-cases in app. Do you think procedure would violate any Apple rule? And so I could avoid to pay the 30%?!

Comment: What did you find out ? Can you avoid the 30% tax ?

Answer (score 0):

Apple guidelines:

> Apps that link to external mechanisms for purchases or subscriptions to be used in the App, such as a “buy” button that goes to a web site to purchase a digital book, will be rejected.

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#purchasing-currencies 11.13

Comment: what about Dropbox? they offer more capacity if you buy premium service on their site?! - but they do not have any `Buy` button in the app , so they are not against the guidelines

Comment: But not within their app? The Upgrade button in the app triggers an iAP through the app store.

Comment: I see, I was not aware of IAP possibility, and  the same upgrade is possible from web too for  €99/year, do you think Apple charge them for 30% too?!

Comment: Maybe there are some special contracts for big companies, I don't know.